# How to generate random numbers/letters with PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I have looked all over but I can't find it. I need a script to generator random captial letters and numbers at the click of a button. I need to have the dash " - " between every 4 characters. Can anyone point me in the right direction or know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to generate random 'things':

1. rand function
2. microtime function
3. uniqid function

Then if you need letters and number you can use md5 function to generate a hash from one of the above.

You can then change the md5 hash to upper case and get what you want (lenght) and insert '-' for every 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
//generate 4 characters random string
 function generateRandomString($length = 4, $letters = '1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'){
    $s = '';
    $lettersLength = strlen($letters)-1;

    for($i = 0 ; $i < $length ; $i++)
    {
        $s .= $letters[rand(0,$lettersLength)];
    }

    return $s;
} 

echo generateRandomString()."-".generateRandomString();
```

Fastest way. Function can be improved though... write it at hand, right now. :)

Comment: Thank you adrian! How do I insert that into HTML? <script> tag and button?

Comment: @user2817557: this is PHP, not JavaScript (that's for the `<script>` tag).  You'd simply place this in the appropriate location of your PHP file (along with your opening and closing PHP tags).

Comment: Ty Qantas, it worked. But how do I increase the length of the generated string? About 20 characters,  NEVERMIND SOLVED.

Comment: Javascript solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript