# creating unique random string

Tags: php, excel, random

I am working in php and I am trying to create 1000 tickets in a database.  Each ticket needs it's own unique code that consists of letters and numbers about 6 characters long.

```
EXP.    
Tbl_Tickets
ID     code
1      3F2jk7
2      2HGUF1       
3      9FJDNJ
4      MFJEY9
5      23988D
```

I was wondering is there a simple way of doing this with php, or excel, or any other way for that matter.  I know that i can use a random number generator, but the check for the Unique would have a large BigO notation and the check would get messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique is not compatible with random, but the following might suit:

`=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),RANDBETWEEN(0,9),CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)))`

copied across to populate six columns (say A to F) with, in G:

`=A1&B1&C1&D1&E1&F1`

and both copied down to say row 1100. Then select G, copy Paste Special Values, and Remove Duplicates on ColumnG and select first 1000 entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create an array of strings in php and write it to a database:

```
 function generateRandomString($length = 6, $letters = '1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'){
    $s = '';
    $lettersLength = strlen($letters)-1;

    for($i = 0 ; $i < $length ; $i++){
        $s .= $letters[rand(0,$lettersLength)];
    }

    return $s;
} 
// Create an array with random strings
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++){
  $ticket_numbers = array();
  $ticket_number = generateRandomString();
  while (in_array($ticket_number,$ticket_numbers))
    $ticket_number = generateRandomString();
  $ticket_numbers[] = $ticket_number;
}
// Write the array to a database
$con = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error");
foreach ($ticket_numbers as $number){
  mysqli_query($con,"Your insert query using the value $number");
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

This should help you in the right direction though there are probably better ways to do this.

The function generateRandomString() was taken from [How to generate random numbers/letters with PHP/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017831/how-to-generate-random-numbers-letters-with-php-javascript)

Comment: I'd recommend `mt_rand` as a replacement for `rand`.  It's a bit faster and it's more reliably random.

Answer (score 0):

And another option.  Encryption is guaranteed to be unique, so encrypting the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... will give you guaranteed unique random-seeming output.  Six characters is 30 bits using Base32, or 36 bits using Base64.  You will need a 30 (or 36 bit) cypher.  Unless you have a library that includes Hasty Pudding cypher (unlikely) then just implement a simple four round [Feistel cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) with the appropriate block size.  It will not be completely secure, but it will be enough to defeat casual attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This will produce random strings in column **B** with **no repeats** from *B1* thru *B1001*

```
Sub Lottery()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    v = Split("0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z", ",")
    For i = 1 To 5000
        can = ""
        For j = 1 To 6
            can = can & v(Application.RandBetween(0, 35))
        Next j
        On Error Resume Next
            c.Add can, CStr(can)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If c.Count = 1000 Then Exit For
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 1000
    Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = c(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```